# Google Map API : Map tiles border is showing

Tags: google-maps-api-3

On http://bluewhalecomputing.appspot.com/contact-us , the map tiles border is showing.  What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of your css causes the problem:

```css
.greeting img {
  border: none;
  /* curved border radius */
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px #777;
}
```